# Make windows login through Face Authentication

Tags: windows, powershell, face-recognition

I have made a Face verification code using opencv, I have made the application in Windows form  VS2010 using C++. Now I want to execute this app on windows login screen and bypass the login when it authenticates the face.

Efforts from my side for this: I have search for this, and now I have idea that I have to write a startup script in powershell for this. But I dont know how to do this. It will be helpful if anybody can give some pointers for where I should look next.

Note: I thought it might not be possible(as a security issue), but I found some people have done this like here: http://face-detection-recognition.com/

Which means its possible to achieve.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you need to create a custom Credention Provider and extend/modify the LogonUI to implement it (face recognition). Unfortunately, I'm no developer so I can't explain any furter. Check out this link:

[Create Custom Login Experiences With Credential Providers For Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx)